# How to get rid of the duplicates in inner join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am joining 3 tables `Opportunity`, `Lead`, `Notes`

```
Select 
     Distinct O.oppo_jobid, O.oppo_status,
     cast(N.Note_Note as NCHAR) as Notes 
from Opportunity O, Notes N
Inner join Notes on o.Oppo_OpportunityId = Notes.Note_ForeignId 
Inner join Lead on o.Oppo_OpportunityId = Lead.Lead_OpportunityID
```

I am getting duplicates. How to avoid duplicates while using inner join?

Main table is `Opportunity` and `Notes` are compared with `opportunity id` and `Notes` table has many records with same opportunity in so the duplicate occurs. Now how I can avoid duplicates while comparing both table and fetching last updated note.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your cast expression `cast(N.Note_Note as NCHAR)` will return a fixed 30 character length column is that definitely the desired result? What is the purpose of the join to `Lead` as well?

Comment: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534939/duplicated-results-when-performing-inner-join) is also easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you don't accidently do an cartesian product here:

```
from Opportunity O, Notes N
```

This should be **only**

```
from Opportunity O
```

You're already INNER joining the Notes table later....

So this query here should hopefully not return any duplicates:

```
Select 
     O.oppo_jobid, O.oppo_status,
     cast(N.Note_Note as NCHAR) as Notes 
from dbo.Opportunity O
Inner join dbo.Notes on o.Oppo_OpportunityId = Notes.Note_ForeignId 
Inner join dbo.Lead on o.Oppo_OpportunityId = Lead.Lead_OpportunityID
```

**Update:** if you want only the most recent `note` for each opportunity - use this query:

```
;WITH MostRecent AS
(
    SELECT 
        O.oppo_jobid, O.oppo_status,
        cast(N.Note_Note as NCHAR) as Notes,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.Oppo_OpportunityId 
                           ORDER BY n.Note_DateTimeStamp DESC) AS 'RowNum'
    FROM dbo.Opportunity O
    INNER JOIN dbo.Notes on o.Oppo_OpportunityId = Notes.Note_ForeignId 
)
SELECT *
FROM MostRecent
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: +1 Was also wondering about the join on `Lead`. Doesn't seem to be used and maybe should be replaced with an `EXISTS` or removed entirely.

Comment: in notes table i had many records with same opportunity id. i need to inner join notes table and check the last update to the recent date.

Comment: SELECT O.Oppo_orderstatus as Status,O.Oppo_jobid as JobID, 
 N.Note_Note as Notes, N.note_jobid as JobId,N.Note_UpdatedBy as UpdateDate,
 Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),O.Oppo_currentprice) as nvarchar) AS  Total, 
 Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),O.Oppo_currentpmts) as nvarchar) AS Payments, 
 O.Oppo_branchid as Branch,O.Oppo_mb AS MB,O.Oppo_statuschgdt AS ChangeDate
 FROM Notes N  INNER JOIN Opportunity O ON O.Oppo_OpportunityId = N.Note_ForeignId
 where Note_UpdatedBy = (Select max(Note_UpdatedBy) from Notes )

Comment: You're not getting **duplicates** - you're just getting several rows since there are multiple notes for each opportunity.... so what do you really want???